# Angular change value based on deployment environment

Tags: javascript, angular

I have dockerized an Angular 9 app that calls a Java RESful api.  When I run them both on my localhost, it works.

Then I deploy both the images to a Linux sever.

I can access the Angular app, but when the Angular app tries to call the RESTful api, it can't because I have the endpoint url as:

```
export const config = {
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8081'
  };
```

**Question**

How do I make the url configurable so that depending on what server I deploy it to, I can change it to that servers IP?

For example,

```
export const config = {
    // if prod
    apiUrl: 'http://<serverIp>:8081'
    // if local
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8081'
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In environments folder, there are 2 files for environment variables, first one called `environment.ts` for development variables, and the second one called `environment.prod.ts` for deployment variables, you can use them for your case
check this article
https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/
Or angular documentation
https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: Thanks. Does that correspond to how you do the `ng build`? i.e. `ng build --prod` will have the `environment.prod.ts` values?

Comment: yes, exactly as you defined that you are in production mode, so angular automatically uses your ` environment.prod.ts ` variables

Comment: You can access it like
` return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/login`); ` and import environment

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [Building and serving Angular apps](https://angular.io/guide/build) it explains how you can do exactly that.

You need to enter your production environment variables in the `environment.prod.ts` and your development variables in the `environment.ts` files, there is even a staging file for staging `environment.stage.ts`

here is how you do it basically.

```
// environment.ts for local machine
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'mydevelopmenturl.com'
};

// environment.ts for production environment
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'myproductionurl.com'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  you and @Emad Abdou both have the same answer. I appreciate the help.